# nginx redirect from subdomain with www to subdomain non-www

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm redirecting my main website non-www to www doing this:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    return 301 http://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name *.domain.com;
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    ...
```

How can I permanently redirect my subdomains http://www.one.domain.com to http://one.domain.in ?

Answer (score 2):

With this you can redirect to www.domain.com to domain.com. If you put this on your subdomains config it works too.

```
server {
     server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
     return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri ;
}
```